# Do not call BlockUI for ajax calls which take little time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using **jQuery BlockUI**. In every **AjaxCall** i am blocking form with **BlockUI Plugin**. But Ajax request may continue 1 second or maybe more than minute. so i don't want to block form when request will take a few second. how i can do it?

Comment: You shouldn't ask a second question in the same question. That's not how we do things here on Stack Overflow. Remove the second part of this question and post it as a new question instead.

Comment: i will delete second part of question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done.

How is your code going to know what ajax calls are going to be simple beforehand?

**Code:** *"I'll start blocking now...."*
**Code:** *"What? Already done? But it was only 1.5 seconds and I'm only supposed to block if the request takes longer than 5 seconds."*
**Code:** *"I'll have to send a message back in time to myself and tell me not to block this call."*

It's up to you to determine when to use BlockUI or not.

Comment: you say that there is no any way to do it

Comment: @AEML - Not without an improvment is space/time research

Comment: Maybe set a timer on each ajax call and then after 5 or 10 seconds, then use BlockUI?

Comment: thanks. i determined places where i want to add BlockUI. you are right there is no another way to do it. i must determine it myself.